# Workaround for storing an image in very low resolution with matplotlib and python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create an **occupancy grid** map by exporting an higher resolution image of the map to a very low resolution.

In most basic form an **occupancy grid** is a 2 dimensional binary array. The values stored in array denotes free(0) or occupied(1). Each value corresponds to a discrete location of the physical map (the following image depicts an area) 
[image: courtsy: mathworks]

As seen in the above image each array location is a cell of physical world.

I have a 5 meter x 5 meter World, it is then discretized into cells of 5cm x 5cm. The world is thus 100 x 100 cells corresponding to 5m x 5m physical world.

The obstacle re randomly generated circular disks at location (**x,y**) and of a random radius **r** like follows:
[image: created world]

I need to covert this (above) image into an array of size 100x100. That means evaluating if each cell is actually in the region of a obstacle or free.

To speed things, I have found the following workaround:

Create matplotlib figure populated with obstacles with `figsize=(5,5)` and save the image with `dpi=20` in **bmp** format and finally import the **bmp image** as an numpy array. Alas, matplotlib does not support **bmp**. If I save the image in jpeg using `plt.savefig('map.jpg', dpi=20, quality=100)` or other formats then the cell's boundary becomes blurred and flows into other cells. Shown in this image :
 [image: map in jpg 100 quality]

So my question: **How to save a scaled-down image from matplotlib that preserves the cell sharpness of image (akin to `bmp`)**.

Comment: How about saving a png? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386096/importing-png-files-into-numpy

Comment: I am getting similar result with `png` format. The size of `png` file lesser than that of `jpg` file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice hack. However, I would rather compute the boolean mask corresponding to your discretized circles explicitly. One simple way to get such a boolean map is by using the `contains_points` method of matplotlib artists such as a `Circle` patch.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

world_width = 100 # x
world_height = 100 # y
minimum_radius = 1
maximum_radius = 10
total_circles = 5

# create circle patches
x = np.random.randint(0, world_width, size=total_circles)
y = np.random.randint(0, world_height, size=total_circles)
r = minimum_radius + (maximum_radius - minimum_radius) * np.random.rand(total_circles)
circles = [Circle((xx,yy), radius=rr) for xx, yy, rr in zip(x, y, r)]

# for each circle, create a boolean mask where each cell element is True
# if its center is within that circle and False otherwise
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(world_width) + 0.5, np.arange(world_height) + 0.5)

masks = np.zeros((total_circles, world_width, world_height), dtype=bool)
for ii, circle in enumerate(circles):
    masks[ii] = circle.contains_points(np.c_[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).reshape(world_width, world_height)

combined_mask = np.sum(masks, axis=0)
plt.imshow(combined_mask, cmap='gray_r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Clean! You did solve the original problem. Thanks for the learning! +1 and before accepting this answer I will wait for some time to see if there is an answer to the workaround question.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, I think this can be done quite simply with PIL, specifically with the `Image.resize` fucntion. For example, does this do what you asked:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Make a dummy image with some black circles on a white background
image = Image.new('RGBA', (1000, 1000), color="white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((20, 20, 180, 180), fill = 'black', outline ='black')
draw.ellipse((500, 500, 600, 600), fill = 'black', outline ='black')
draw.ellipse((100, 800, 250, 950), fill = 'black', outline ='black')
draw.ellipse((750, 300, 800, 350), fill = 'black', outline ='black')
image.save('circles_full_res.png')

# Resize the image with nearest neighbour interpolation to preserve grid sharpness
image_lo = image.resize((100,100), resample=0)
image_lo.save("circles_low_res.png")
```

Comment: Thank you for prividing this script! The results I obtained with this script seem similar: please take a look at this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l3jgDqR-_LyElh4hL8QTMrtGCElpddgY/view?usp=sharing and let me know your thoughts. I think this happens because of the compression. `bmp` meanwhile is uncompressed and can retain the pixel boundary sharpness.